# Firebase update fields only when its empty

Tags: android, firebase, validation, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a data set on firebase real time database like this.

```
Users
---Match
   ------User1
         mId:"12345"
         xId:""
   ------User2
         mId:"54321"
         xId:""
```

Basically developing a multi player matching functionality here using **android** application.Assuming user 1 matched with user 2. **User1** will update his own **xId** value with **user2** **mId** value and **user2** will update his own **xId** value with **mId** value of **user1**.
This works fine if there are two users. Both connects to each other and works well. Issue comes when 3 users come at the same time. User1 writes to user2 and user2 writes to user3 and creates inconsistent data set. 
I want to lock a value once it is changed or we can say a simple rule like.

```
update user1 only : if(user1.xid=="")
update user2 only : if(user2.xid=="")
```

Is it possible using firebase security rule?

Answer (score 1):

To only allow writing new data (so never overwrite or delete existing data), you'll want this rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "Match": {
        "uid": {
          ".validate": "!data.child('xid').exists() && newData.child('xid').exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more elaborate information check out the [Firebase documentation for security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security), specifically the section on [New vs. Existing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).